# Scan function is not working inside a loop

Tags: c, scanf

Could someone explain to me why the "scan" function is not working in the following code? What do I do to fix the problem? Thanks!

```
int main() {
    int age, sumage;
    float mean;
    sumage = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a <= 20; a = a + 1) {
        printf("Enter age: \n");
        scanf("%d", &age);
        sumage = sumage + age;
    }
    mean = sumage/20;
    printf("mean = é %f \n" , mean);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "is not working" means.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &age)` is working.  It is other code that is working, but not as you want.  Look at `mean = sumage/20;` as an integer problem.

Comment: Read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html): you should always test its result (number of scanned items).

Comment: I want to read 20 ages, but scanf just reads the first one. The application keeps running, but nothing happens anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
mean = sumage/20;
```

Here `sumage` is an integer. Thus the division is integer division.

Change into `(float)sumage / 20.0` to get expected result.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be `(float)sumage / 20.0f` or just `sumage / 20.0f`. The double literal will enforce the division to be done with double precision, which is then truncated to float. Makes the program needlessly slow unless the compiler manages to optimize.

Comment: I want to read 20 ages, but scanf just reads the first one. The application keeps running, but nothing happens anymore. I tried everything, all var integers, double, it wouldn't work. The application basically stops at scanf.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to fill a `float` with an `integer` value:

```
mean = sumage/20;
```

needs a `cast` to `float` to store the value as a `float`:

```
mean = (float) sumage/20;
```

Bottom line, `int/int` = `int`, unless cast otherwise. The **C99** reference for arithmetic conversion is:

> **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is float.51)

Comment: Not really to *store the value as a float*, but rather *to calculate as float* (and the `(float)` casting applies to *sumage* btw)

Comment: And `float`/`int` = `float`